# How does Foldable knows the implementation of mappend

Tags: haskell, monoids, foldable

I am learning Haskell with the help of "http://learnyouahaskell.com". I am following the example of a BST (*Binary Search Tree*) that is an instance of `Foldable`:

```
data Tree a = Nil | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

instance F.Foldable Tree where
    foldMap f Nil = mempty
    foldMap f (Node x l r) = (F.foldMap f l) `mappend` (f x) `mappend` (F.foldMap f r)
```

When I run `F.foldMap (\x -> [x]) testTree` I get a list that represents the folded tree.
I implemented my own data type:

```
newtype OnlySum a = OnlySum {value :: a} deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show, Bounded)
instance Num a => Monoid (OnlySum a) where
    mempty = OnlySum 0
    OnlySum x `mappend` OnlySum y = OnlySum (x + y)
```

And ran this command: `F.foldMap (\x -> OnlySum x) testTree` to obtain the tree folded as this `OnlySum {value = 34}`.

The question is: **How does Foldable know the definition of `mempty` and `mappend` depending on the return type of the function `f` passed to `foldMap`?** Does it infer it or is there a way for Haskell to automatically know which is the definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [definition of foldMap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html) we see that it requires a typeclass instance `Monoid m`. So Haskell knows that `mappend` is coming from `Monoid`. The specific type will be inferred, then a `Monoid` typeclass instance resolved based on that type, and that typeclass is what will be used.

Comment: So it's basically polymorphism, isn't it?

Comment: @OneEyeQuestion Yes, it's just polymorphism on the return type.

Comment: Yes, so types do more than make trouble for you. Types cause boring run time code to be cranked out for you. When writing types saves you writing code, it might even be worth putting up with them.